# xpath for first post on instagram profile not working (python, selenium, chromedriver)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, instagram

I am trying to click on the first post after navigating to any Instagram profile. I looked at the `xpath` of the first post of multiple Instagram user's profiles and they all seem to be the same. Here is an example of messi's profile.

Here is my attempt with using chromedriver with python to click on Messi's first post. I have already navigated to `https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/`, which is Messi's profile.

```
first_post_elem_click = driver.find_element_by_path('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div[4]/article/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div').click()
```

However, the first post is not being clicked on. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below solution,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


Browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

Browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/")

WebDriverWait(Browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//body//div[contains(@class,'_2z6nI')]//div//div//div[1]//div[1]//a[1]//div[1]//div[2]"))).click()
```

Comment: Great !! would you kind enough to hit upvote button from your end.

Comment: yes of course, I just did. I have just joined, so it says it will not be shown here, but it has been recorded.

Comment: can you please explain how you determined this xpath? would appreciate an explanation, so I can try myself for future implementations. I am having similar problems with trying to hit the next button.

Comment: ok ... its quite straight forward actually when you launched your URL then you have body tag under body we need to check post so i have selected div which is having _2z6nI. After that I simply avoided blank divs horizaontally and vertically and then selected first div

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain. _2z6nl class makes sense. Where does this come from: //div//div//div[1]//div[1]//a[1]//div[1]//div[2]? for instance how would I change this to hit the second post and third post etc? I am new to html.

Comment: you have to go through DOM structure to understand it properly

Comment: @AD xpath finder is browsers feature in built in chrome. right click & Inspect ur html tag, select copy then select copy as xpath. Hope this will help for future.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the absolute xpath, you should be using relative xpath.
You can click on the first post using the below command(Have applied Explicit wait as well):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='Nnq7C weEfm']//img)[1]"))).click()
```

**You need to add the following imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I tried this, but it did not work either :(

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked this in Firefox: `$x('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/descendant::article/descendant::a[1]')`. That should give you what you want, I think.

Comment: Thank you. Are you suggesting:driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/descendant::article/descendant::a[1]').click() this did not work either :(